# Finding libraries with pkg-config in a Homebrew formula?

Tags: macos, homebrew, configure, pkg-config

I’m attempting to build a Homebrew formula that depends on `pkg-config` during installation. I have the appropriate `depends_on "pkg-config" => :build` statement in the formula, but upon calling `./configure` I get warnings that `pkg-config` cannot find a library. I know the `depends_on` call is doing something, because it fixed an earlier issue with `./configure` being unable to find `pkg-config`.

When using verbose mode, Homebrew tells me that `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` is missing the `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. I’ve tried changing the variable by calling `system "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=$PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure", "--exec-prefix=#{prefix}"` in my formula but the script still fails every time.

What is the correct way to fix this issue in Homebrew?

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` is intentionally missing and you should not need to add it back. Adding a dependency for the package that you need with `depends_on` should add its prefixed pkgconfig path to the search path.

Comment: Unfortunately the dependencies are not being found by pkg-config, even with the appropriate `depends_on` statements:

`  depends_on "libexif" => :build
  depends_on "libjpeg" => :build
  depends_on "libid3tag" => :build
  depends_on "flac" => :build
  depends_on "libvorbis" => :build
  depends_on "sqlite3" => :build
  depends_on "libav" => :build
  depends_on "imagemagick" => :build
  depends_on "intltool" => :build
  depends_on "gettext" => :build
  depends_on "autoconf" => :build
  depends_on "automake" => :build
  depends_on "libtool" => :build
  depends_on "pkg-config" => :build`

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems Homebrew is overriding the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.